# Swift with nested ForEach or For in

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, nested-loops

Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0
2021-04-20 19:17:54.685999-0500 PetGram[17828:1053156] Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0

I can't figure it out.  It only crashes on a second user follow.  Once you relaunch you can follow and unfollow and it works fine.  If you unfollow until you are below 2 and follow another it crashes again.  Any help would be great.

```
func loadFilteredPosts() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        FB.USER_COLLECTION.whereField(FB.USER_FOLLOWERS, arrayContains: uid)
            .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("DEBUG: Error getting followers from user docs \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    if let snapshot = snapshot {
                        self.filteredUsers = snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                            try? document.data(as: User.self)
                        }
                    }
                    self.posts.forEach { post in
                        self.filteredUsers.forEach { user in
                            if user.uid == post.ownerUid {
                                self.filteredPosts.append(post)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do you ever clear out `filteredPosts`? I see you're appending to it, but there's nothing that removes elements. If you end up with multiple copies of identical entities in there in your layout (which you aren't showing), that could cause this crash.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Frank.  Much appreciated, worked like a charm. self.filteredPosts.removeAll() before forEach